# How to find the code for color I like?

Tags: colors

There is a color I like in an image, but how can I find the code [ i.e. #FFC6A5 ] for it ? The image is in .png format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file in an image editing program, then use the Eyedropper tool to select that color. You should be able to retrieve the hex value from there.

Alternatively, you could download [ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/). It's a free utility that allows you to do the same thing, but without opening the image first. You can simply move the Eyedropper tool around the screen and select any color you hover over (whether it's in an image or not).

Comment: @Frank No problem. In the future, a question like this (that's not related to programming) would probably be better suited on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

[ColorZilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/271/) lets you do this. Its a handy Firefox Add-on. Of course you will hav to open the image in firefox but its handy if you want to know the color code of an image in a website.